# Proxy Authentication With Fluent API Request?

Tags: request, client, fluent-interface

I am currently using a Get Request with proxy information:

```
String result1 = Request.Get("_http://somehost/")
        .version(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1)
        .connectTimeout(1000)
        .socketTimeout(1000)
        .viaProxy(new HttpHost("myproxy", 8080))
        .execute().returnContent().asString();
```

The result is a "Proxy Authentication Required" error.  I believe a username and password is required from the server making the request?  If so, how do I add that detail?  I have never used the Fluent API before.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using the Fluent API. The executor can be used to specify credentials for the proxy.

```
    HttpHost proxyHost = new HttpHost("myproxy", 8080);

    Executor executor = Executor.newInstance()
        .auth(proxyHost, "username", "password");

    String result1 = executor.execute(Request.Get("_http://somehost/")
        .viaProxy(proxyHost))
        .returnContent()
        .asString();
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Can you please [edit] your answer and add a short commentary or description to explain how it works? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need a `CredentialsProvider`.

```
final CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(proxy), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));

final HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);
httppost.setConfig(RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(proxy).build());

String line = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build() .execute(httppost).getStatusLine());
```

Also, there was a bug in 4.3.1 that impacted authentication.  It is fixed in 4.3.2.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1435

Answer (score 0):

```
Executor executor = Executor.newInstance()
        .auth(new HttpHost("myproxy", 8080), "username", "password")
        .authPreemptive(new HttpHost("myproxy", 8080));
Response response = executor.execute(<your reques>);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your answer will be more helpful if you explain what makes your answer better than the existing (and very similar) answers.