# Fluent Httpclient java - proxy authentication - bad request error

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I am trying to use proxyIP to make api calls.
ProxyIP requires username and password to authenticate.I am setting those as per other [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15482903/proxy-authentication-with-fluent-api-request) and mentioned [here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fluent.html)

But I am getting following error

```
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Bad Request
```

Not sure what i am missing.Any help is appreciated.

Code :

```
    String response = Executor.newInstance()
        .auth(new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort), "proxyuser", "proxypass")
        .authPreemptiveProxy(new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort))
        .execute(Request.Get("http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com/")
            .viaProxy(new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort))
             .setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 "
            + "Firefox/64.0"))
        .returnContent()
        .asString();
```

HttpComponentVersion : 4.3.6

Comment: Upgrade to HC 4.5.6

Comment: I am trying in 4.5.2 same issue, will it work only in 4.5.6